# Apply comparison to a list in Python?

Tags: python, comparison

I am trying to compare elements of a list `u` for equality.

A possible solution could be `all(x == u[0] for x in u[1:])`, or simply `all(x == u[0] for x in u)`, but it looks rather weird.

In Python, it's possible to write `a == b == c`, with its usual "mathematical" meaning. So I thought I could, with the help of the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module, write `operator.eq(*u)`. However, the `eq` function takes only two arguments. Of course, `functools.reduce(operator.eq, u)` is of no use here, since after the first test `eq(u[0], u[1])`, I get a boolean, and it will fail when doing the second test, `eq(<bool>, u[2])`.

Is there a better way than the solution above? A more... "pythonic" way?

Comment: If they’re hashable, you can use `len(set(u)) == 1`, but that’s just shorter, not better. `all` seems straightforward to me.

Comment: Argh, I didn't see the duplicate. Thanks @jamylak to have pointed this out.

Answer (score 0):

`len(set(u)) == 1` is pretty Pythonic.

Comment: But it returns the wrong answer for an empty input (you should do `<= 1` instead of `== 1`) and it doesn't work if any elements in your list aren't hashable and doesn't short circuit, i.e. if you can tell that the first two elements aren't equal it'll still have to process the whole list. It also requires double the memory (if all the elements in your array are unique).